# Dump structure and data of schema

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, pg-dump

I executed the following command:

```
pg_dump -h 10.100.1.2 -U user -n schema1 > backup.sql
```

This command creats a dump of schema "schema1", but the dump generated has only  the structure of schema.

How I can generate a dump of schema with the structure and data (INSERT)?

Comment: That command **will** include the data. Did you maybe use `-s schema1` instead? If you are sure you used `-n schema1` then the tables in that schema contain no data.

Comment: see the documentation for a full list of flags and usage:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pgdump.html

the command above includes the data.
if you used `-s` then it won't.
if you want only data use the `-a` flag.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `-n` from the command and run.
i.e.

`pg_dump -h 10.100.1.2 -U user schema1 > backup.sql`

`-n` flag tells PostgreSQL to dump the named schema(s) only, not the data.